# Not a function error on TypeScript object after Casting

Tags: angular, typescript

I made an http call using Angular5 http client. In map function I have done the casting of the response to a PersonModel.

PersonModel has a function getFullName() which returns first_name + last_name

After doing the casting when I try to access this method on casted person object this shows an error of getFullName is not a function.

```
export class PersonModel {
constructor(
                public first_name: string = null,
                public middle_name: string = null,
                public last_name: string = null) {

    }

getFullName() {
        return this.first_name + this.last_name;
    }

}
```

**This is the service**

```
get(id: number): Observable<PersonModel> {
            return this.http.get("customer/" + id)
                .map((response: any) => {
                    return <PersonModel>response;
                });
        }


customerService.get(1).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result.getFullName());
})
```

**Error**
core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: person.getFullName is not a function

**Log for object:**

```
{first_name: "kjlkj", last_name: "jnkjh"}
```

However when I create an object like this:

```
const person = new PersonModel();
person.first_name = "lkj";
person.last_name= "lkj";
```

then this logs as this:

```
PersonModel {first_name: "kjlkj", last_name: "jnkjh"}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code as a [mcve].

Comment: Above is the code in description

Comment: @XyrinTechnologies Please post the full error too. The more information, the better.

Comment: @Carcigenicate found that ! : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000 . Thanks again. Will clean my comments here in a minute.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Added, The complete info contains the file which wont be much useful to you :)

Comment: You does not need do this map in angular 5;

Comment: The error mentions `person.getFullName`, but I don't see you calling that anywhere. Where is that code? And have you checked what `person` is?

Comment: As a simple guess, I think you have to made your class method getFullName as public

Comment: I used person.getFullName() inside subscribe. Actually, its a 1k+ line of the code for a component. That's why sharing the code completely wont help.

Comment: @Pac0 making the public does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @jrelo if I don't map then please suggest what's the solution. I would love to go for that.

Comment: show your subscribe

Comment: *"Actually, its a 1k+ line of the code for a component. That's why sharing the code completely wont help"*, Yes of course, and that's why we strongly encourage (and even require) a MCVE for this kind of questions. If you put some effort to reduce the code to a postable and readable subset that exhibits the error, it will help as much yourself as the others persons to debug your code and narrow down the issue to something answerable.

Comment: @jrelo Added in description.

Comment: @Pac0 I have update the description, please see if this helps else I will try to setup some portable code.

Comment: can you also show the result of `console.log(result)` in your subscribe ?

Comment: @XyrinTechnologies I meant "postable" as "not too long so you can post it there" ;) (sorry if my English is not good)

Comment: @Pac0 ERROR TypeError: result.getFullName is not a function

Comment: @XyrinTechnologies if you write : `customerService.get(1).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
})`  instead, what is the result in console ?

Comment: @Pac0 actually the concern is the converting the JSON into Model using casting is not allowing to call function of the model. 

Ex.

We have a json:
{first_name: "John", last_name: "David"}

When we cast this to model and then call a function then this throws error for function not found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well , wellcome to JS/TS world.

When you cast basically it is just to avoid type "errors" on your IDE in typescript, and to be sure certain attributes exist on the object but not functions...

```js
class Dog {
    public name: string = "";

    bark(): void {
        console.log("whoof whoof");
    } 
}


let johnny = new Dog();
johnny.name = "johnny";
johnny.bark(); // => Barks ok

let onlyattrs = {
    name: "err"
} as Dog;

// onlyattrs.bark(); // => function does not exists

let realDog = new Dog();
realDog = Object.assign(realDog, onlyattrs);

realDog.bark(); // => barks ok
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get(id: number): Observable<PersonModel> {
   return this.http.get('customer/' + id).pipe(
      map(p:any=> {return new PersonModel(p.first_name,p.middle_name,p.last_name)});
   );
}
```

Comment: log what the get request is receiving so we can look at the object

Comment: @jrelo same issue, please check my last edits for description.

Comment: I mean, log the http get, not your own object, I want to see what is comming through in the http request: console.log(response)

Comment: you change your PersonModel to my implementation?